# Как инициализировать статический объект класса?

Tags: c++

На пример есть класс:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
//...
private:
static std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> dict;
};
```

Как мне инициализировать разные ключи dict значениями в cpp файле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где-то в .cpp файле

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> MyClass::dict = {{"asd", 1}, {"sdfg", 2}};
```

Или так:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> MyClass::dict = [] {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> result;
    result["asd"] = 1;
    result[getKey() + ".xxx"] = 3;
    return result;
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
//...
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> dict;
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> MyClass::dict {{"2",1},{"4",2},{"6",3}};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MyClass m;
    for(auto x: m.dict)
        cout << x.first << "  " << x.second << endl;
}
```

Словом, инициализировать `MyClass::dict` как обычную глобальную переменную :)

Comment: думаю стоит пометить, что стоит это сделать не в хэдэре, а в cpp файле, иначе, если хэдэр с классом включить в нескольких сpp файлах - это чреватой ошибкой компиляции.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Но в вопросе это уже оговорено: *"Как мне инициализировать разные ключи dict значениями* **в cpp** *файле?"*

Comment: а, верно, не заметил

Answer (score 0):

Напишите метод `public: static void InitMap();` который в `main` и вызовите `MyClass::InitMap();`